# Array of string request body resulting to Error Description : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jquery-select2

Firstly, I do not know what would be the title exactly as I really do not understand the cause of the problem. I find it really wierd.

**Problem:**

```
Error Description : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

**Findings:**
This works when the request value sent is in this format `nicknames: "Borgy, Frederick, Carlo"`.

In the server side, the values became `["Borgy", "Frederick", "Carlo"]` and will be stored in DB as that value (json type column).

The problem seems to be with the StringArrayConverter and the format of the data (nicknames) as it is sent from the UI/page.

It would really be nice if I could send the data as:

```
nicknames[]: Borgy
nicknames[]: Frederick
nicknames[]: Carlo
```

then it will be stored in DB (json type column) as `["Borgy", "Frederick", "Carlo"]`. I think the change will be done on the StringArrayConverter... not sure... just a wild guess.

**Note:**
*There is no string to integer (or any number) conversion involved, find it weird why I am getting the number format exception.*

*Also, when the value nickname is only one (ex: "['butitoy']"), it will work... but if it is more that one (ex: "['butitoy', 'gwapitoy']"), it will result to number format exception.*

*The error is self explanatory... but I really do not know how and where the error is. I tried debugging but it would not go inside the validation request.  the field nickname is of String[] type and is a MySQL JSON Type column, but I think the problem cause is not on the JSON Type column.*

**Case:**
I have a simple validation request having an object request body. This is submitted via POST.
This project is a Spring MVC project.

**Request:**
POST http://localhost:8080/admin/account-validation

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/account-validation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Layout(value = ConstantUtil.THYMELEAF_TEMPLATE_NONE)
public @ResponseBody ValidationResponse accountValidation(@Valid Account account,
        BindingResult result) {
    // It wont go inside here
    ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();
    ...
    return res;
}
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    private String m_name;
    private String m_code;
    private String[] m_nicknames;
    private Boolean m_deletedInd;


    //Getters
    ...

    //Take note MySQL JSON Type column, nullable
    @Column(name = "nicknames", columnDefinition = "json")
    @Convert(converter = StringArrayConverter.class)
    public String[] getNicknames() {
        return m_nicknames;
    }

    ...

    //Setters
    ...

}
```

**Converter:**

```
@Converter
public class StringArrayConverter implements AttributeConverter<String[], String> {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StringArrayConverter.class);

    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String[] arrayObj) {
        if (arrayObj != null) {
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(arrayObj);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] convertToEntityAttribute(String jsonString) {
        if (!Util.isEmptyOrNull(jsonString)) {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(jsonString, String[].class);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                logger.error("[STRING-ARRAY-CONVERTER-ERROR]: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Request Form Data:**

```
name: Dummy
code: DUMMY
nicknames[]: Borgy
nicknames[]: Frederick
nicknames[]: Carlo
_csrf: a93731b5-83db-4bb4-83cc-ed5f91e13aac
```

**Exception from Log:**

```
2018-04-27 22:37:46 [http-nio-8080-exec-101] ERROR c.p.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler -
        -------- Error Start for URL (http://localhost:8080/admin/account-validation) -------------
2018-04-27 22:37:46 [http-nio-8080-exec-101] ERROR c.p.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler -
        Error Description : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:859)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:755)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.bindRequestParameters(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.bihagay.iyot.ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.pac4j.springframework.security.web.CallbackFilter.doFilter(CallbackFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-04-27 22:37:46 [http-nio-8080-exec-101] ERROR c.p.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler -
        -------- Error End for URL (http://localhost:8080/admin/account-validation) -------------
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try to change `private String[] m_nicknames;` to `private List<String> m_nicknames;` and see if it helps?

Comment: Post the request POST body, you use the entity as dto for the request, but JPA annotation are ignored during REST body marshalling